# How to redirect http://domain.com to https://www.domain.com?

Tags: php, wordpress, .htaccess, redirect, ssl

I already got an SSL certificate.
I got Wordpress installed see folder structure in my hostgator file manager below:

I already put `define('FORCE_SSL_ADMIN', true);` in `wp_config.php`

Wordpress General settings:
WordPress Address (URL): https://www.domain.com/blog
Site Address (URL): https://www.domain.com

```
public_html
  -> blog (inside is the wordpress installation)

database structure
  -> wp_options
      -> siteurl: https://www.domain.com/blog
      -> home: https://www.domain.com
```

I tried hostgator cpanel redirects, but not works.

I also tried some of the solutions editing `.htaccess` while searching in google.

Maybe I missed on something regarding with the folder structure.

`.htaccess`:

```
# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On

RewriteBase /blog/

RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /blog/index.php [L]
</IfModule>

# END WordPress
```

Comment: Please post your current htaccess rules for word press.

Comment: Did you tried changing the .htaccess like RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !=on
RewriteRule ^(.*) https://%{SERVER_NAME}/$1 [R,L]  this?

Comment: I already tried this outside of # BEGIN WordPress still didn't work.

Answer (score 3):

You typically just add the rules to your wordpress rules. They go before wp rules.

```
RewriteEngine On
#rewrite http to https and add www. All cases covered
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !^on [OR]
RewriteRule %{HTTP_HOST} ^exmaple\.com [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://www.example.com/$1 [R=301,L]

# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /blog/

RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /blog/index.php [L]
</IfModule>

# END WordPress
```

Comment: FYI, resaving permalinks will delete the SSL rules when used inside the `# BEGIN WordPress` block.

Comment: I moved the rules out of the block. However haven't had that issue, either way it should solve the issue.

Comment: Still didn't work. I think this matter with the folder structure in my file manager.

This is the scenarios: When I type in domain.com it loads but the css and js doesn't but when I typed https://www.domain.com all is fine.

Comment: Wait, explain `Still didn't work`. Does it redirect at all?

Answer (score 1):

You will need 2 virtual hosts, one for port 443 (https) and one for port 80. In the port 80 you could simply setup a redirect rule for all traffic

```
  <VirtualHost *:80>
  ...
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteRule .* https://www.domain.com [R=301,L]
  ...
  </VirtualHost>
```

Answer (score 0):

Use

```
RewriteCond %{SERVER_PORT} 80
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://www.example.com/$1 [R=301,L]

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^example\.com [NC] 
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://www.example.com/$1 [R=301,L]
```

to force SSL on all conditions (with or without the `www`).

Also, as you have done, change to `https` in Wordpress General settings.

**Do not** add the force SSL rule inside the `# BEGIN WordPress` and `# END WordPress` rewrite block, becuase if you ever resave permalinks (or even a plugin does) your SSL rules will be deleted.

And then use the developer tools in [Firefox](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Tools) (or [Firebug](http://getfirebug.com/)) or [Chrome](https://developers.chrome.com/devtools/) or [Safari](https://developer.apple.com/safari/tools/) or [IE](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ie/hh673541(v=vs.85).aspx) to see if you have any `non-secure`element errors, such as from hardcoded `http://` URLs in stylesheets and functions.php files.

Comment: Thanks @markratledge, I tried this but still didn't work. Do you consider the folder structure in my cpanel file manager?

Comment: OK, if that doesn't work, it's an issue with the different of the site address and the WordPress address. Move your whole site to root: see http://codex.wordpress.org/Moving_WordPress and https://interconnectit.com/products/search-and-replace-for-wordpress-databases/

Answer (score 0):

This is my last resorts for the fix. I put up a php code in the header.php that checks if the inputted url is https if not then it redirects to the url with https.

```
<?php
    if (empty($_SERVER['HTTPS'])) {
        header('Location: https://domain.com');
        exit;
    }
?>
```

Thanks all,